# OCR for different sizes of text with NN?

Tags: neural-network, ocr, pattern-recognition

How to deal with recognition of a pattern where the input character font size in the image is different in size than the those it was trained with? How do I input this to my trained neural network?At the moment I just know about feed-forward neural networks and I assume they are sufficient for it.Do I need something else?

Comment: Depending on the approach, you could "downsize" the character image or train your network with the new sizes.

Comment: @MarioWerner but the input is dependent on the image size , isn't it? and what about when I have a smaller font size as input

Comment: The input depends on what your Input Pattern sizes are. If you have 20x20 (=400 Input Neurons) then you cannot apply a larger or smaller image than that without scaling it. It always has to fit into the Input Pattern dimensions.

Answer (score 3):

Most practical systems do some preprocessing like edge detection followed by characted extraction and character scaling (see this paper [for example](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.301.4234&rep=rep1&type=pdf)). Thus, all characters are scaled to the same size. One can try other approaches, for example training NN to recognize some small window as part of character or not part of character (while given larger context window), and then merging adjacent parts (like its done with face recognition). For more info on this topic see [this paper](http://liris.cnrs.fr/Documents/Liris-6079.pdf) that discusses possibilities for text detection with NN without preprocessing

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Very interessting papers. Gonna read. :D